# Why can't customer edit address in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I think this picture describes my problem
[image]

This happens after customer logs in and clicks edit address in their dashboard. I have looked at the layout files and template files but couldn't find anything. 
I get this error message:

> Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Name
>   could not be converted to string  in customer/form/edit.phtml

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

**EDIT the source code for edit.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.

org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Edit Account Information') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/editPost') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Account Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getCustomer()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getCustomer()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="control">
                <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change_password" value="1" onclick="setPasswordForm(this.checked)" title="<?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?>"<?php if($this->getCustomer()->getChangePassword()==1): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" /><label for="change_password"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset" style="display:none;">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <label for="current_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Current Password') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Current Password') ?>" class="input-text" name="current_password" id="current_password" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('New Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('New Password') ?>" class="input-text validate-password" name="password" id="password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm New Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm New Password') ?>" class="input-text validate-cpassword" name="confirmation" id="confirmation" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Save') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
    function setPasswordForm(arg){
        if(arg){
            $('current_password').up(3).show();
            $('current_password').addClassName('required-entry');
            $('password').addClassName('required-entry');
            $('confirmation').addClassName('required-entry');

        }else{
            $('current_password').up(3).hide();
            $('current_password').removeClassName('required-entry');
            $('password').removeClassName('required-entry');
            $('confirmation').removeClassName('required-entry');
        }
    }
    <?php if($this->getCustomer()->getChangePassword()): ?>
        setPasswordForm(true);
    <?php endif; ?>
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: source of customer/form/edit.phtml ?

Comment: Did you or any customer extension make any changes to this block customer/widget_name? Try commenting out this line <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?> to see if this is what causing the error (make sure clear cache if enable). If the error disappear then let me see the content of the block listed above.

Comment: This is probably caused by an extension. Disable the local and community extensions one by one until this form shows up again. Then you will know which extension caused the problem. You can disable extensions in the Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced. Disable all extensions which don't start with Mage_ one by one.

Comment: @R.S I did as you said and commented out the line, I don't get any errors in log but the block stil looks the same. The user can't edit the addresses because there are none. Any more ideas?

Comment: @i.amniels also tried disabling all none Mage_ modules. Didn't work either. Any more ideas?

Comment: Check the content of this file /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Widget/Name.php and customer/widget/name.phtml

Comment: What should I check? I have the files open? Or do you mean the error logs?

Comment: Did you refresh your configuration cache and disable the compiler after you disabled modules?